# WinApi: CW_USEDEFAULT vs. CW_DEFAULT

Tags: c++, winapi

After trying to setup a new C++ WinApi project, and not getting the window to show (albeit showing an icon in the task bar), I realised that in the call to `CreateWindow()`, I was passing `CW_DEFAULT` instead of `CW_USEDEFAULT` to the position of the window (`x` and `y`, see the documentation of [CreateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx)). I've not managed to find anything about them from my google searches. My question is thus the difference between `CW_USEDEFAULT` and `CW_DEFAULT`, in regards to `CreateWindow` and its variations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CW_DEFAULT` is defined in `float.h` and is used with functions to control the behaviour of floating point arithmetic. It has no relationship at all to `CreateWindow`.

The use of `CW_USEDEFAULT` with `CreateWindow` is clearly documented in the documentation for [`CreateWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679.aspx).

Comment: Any reason for the `CW_` prefix of `CW_DEFAULT`? Thought it was an abbreviation of CreateWindow

Comment: That is an unfortunate similarity in names!

Comment: @feareoc: according to `float.h` the "CW" stands for "Control Word".  It's a value for a register in the 80x87 floating point coprocessor.

Comment: @MichaelBurr yeah I see now, that's an unfortunate naming similarity between two very different and unrelated things, explains why it didn't work.